# Check if value is found in SQL table within PHP script?

Tags: php, sql

I need to be able to check and see in a certain string is anywhere within my SQL table. The table I am using only has one column of char's. Right now it is saying that everything entered is already within the table, even when it actually is not.

Within SQL I am getting the rows that have the word using this:

```
SELECT * FROM ADDRESSES WHERE STREET LIKE '%streeetName%';
```

However, in PHP the word is being entered by the user, and then I am storing it as a variable, and then trying to figure out a way to see if that variable is somewhere within the table.

```
 $duplicate = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ADDRESSES WHERE STREET_NAME LIKE '%$streetName%'", $connect);
    if(!empty($duplicate))
    {
       echo "Sorry, only one of each address allowed.<br /><hr>";
    }
```

Comment: How about you count the rows returned by the query? And there is **no more support** for `mysql_*` functions, they are [**officially deprecated**](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation), **no longer maintained** and [**removed**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php#warning) in PHP 7.0.0. You should update your code with [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) to ensure the functionality of your project in the future.

Comment: First thing, don't use `mysql_*` function, instead use `mysqli_*` functions. use check `mysql_num_rows() > 0` means some rows return from the query

Comment: You need to ditch `mysql` and go for the PDO or Improved standards (mysqli) with PHP, `mysql` is depreciated as of the last few builds of PHP.  
_"The original MySQL extension is now deprecated, and will generate E_DEPRECATED errors when connecting to a database. Instead, use the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extensions."_ [PHP 5.5+ Depreciated Features](http://php.net/manual/en/migration55.deprecated.php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do a little bit more than building the query, as `mysql_query` only returns the resource, which doesn't give you any information about the actual result. Using something like `mysql_num_rows` should work.

```
$duplicate = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ADDRESSES WHERE STREET_NAME LIKE '%$streetName%'", $connect);
if(mysql_num_rows($duplicate))
{
   echo "Sorry, only one comment per person.<br /><hr>";
}
```

> Note: the `mysql_*` functions are deprecated and even removed in PHP 7. You should use PDO instead.

Comment: Makes sense! Worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

In the SQL you used

> %streeetName%

But in the query string below, you used

> %$streeetName%

Change the correct one

Answer (score 0):

```
 $duplicate = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ADDRESSES WHERE STREET_NAME LIKE '%$streetName%'", $connect);
if(!empty($duplicate))
{
   echo "Sorry, only one comment per person.<br /><hr>";
}
```

`if($results->num_rows)` is what you need to check if you have results back from your query. An example of connection and query, check, then print or error handle, the code is loose and not checked for errors. Best of luck...

```
//Typically your db connect will come from an includes and/or class User...
$db = new mysqli('localhost','user','pass','database');
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `addresses` WHERE `street_name` LIKE '%$streetName%'",$connect;
//test your queries in PHPMyAdmin SQL to make sure they are properly configured.
//store the results of your query in a variable 
$results = $db->query($sql);
$stmt = '';//empty variable to hold the values of the query as it runs through the while loop
###########################################################
#check to see if you received results back from your query#
###########################################################
if($results->num_rows){
        //loop through your results and echo or assign the values as needed
        while($row = $results->fetch_assoc()){
            echo "Street Name: ".$row['STREET_NAME'];
            //define more variables from your DB query using the $row[] array.
            //concatenate values to a variable for printing in your choice further down the document.
            $address .= $row['STREET_NAME'].' '.$row['CITY'].' '$row['STATE'].' '$row['ZIP'];
        }

}else{ ERROR HANDLING }
```